# Interpretation of measurements and Eigenstates for continuous variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

I find myself (probably like many others) somewhat unclear on the implications of the postulate of quantum mechanics that "measurements of a value leave the system in an eigenstate". The interpretation of this is clear (if philisophically muddled) for measurements of discrete values such as the energy of an harmonic oscillator in a superposition of energy eigenstates: a single eigenvalue is obtained, and the system is left in the eigenstate corresponding to that eigenvalue, with the probabilities determined by the mod-squared amplitudes of the superposed eigenstates.

I find myself unclear, though, on the interpretation of this for the measurement of a continuous value such as position. Clearly, the system cannot be left after measurement in an eigenstate of the position operator, both on the grounds that this would leave it in a complete superpostion of momentum states (which appears to me completely unphysical and not observed in experiment), and that a dirac delta function, while useful conceptually, is not a well behaved and well defined mathematical function that could serve as the physical distribution of some form of real matter.

It seems apparent to me that some part of my reasoning here is flawed - either the understanding that measurment leaves a system in an egienstate, or in my understanding of what it would physically mean for a particle to be in an eigenstate of a continuous variable. Help finding the hole would be appreciated!

Comment: Possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/440363/are-eigenstates-of-the-position-operator-continuous?rq=1

Comment: You cannot measure position with infinite precision in an experiment. You can only measure if a particle is within a certain volume and the probability of this measurement would be the integral of the square of the wavefunction on that volume.

Comment: So, to be clear, it is my understanding of the phrase "measurement leaves the system in an eigenstate" that is at fault? Measurements of continuous variables leave a system in a superposition of position eigenstates corresponding to the precision of the measurement?

Comment: yes it does not apply to operators with continuous spectrum. Rather, you measure if your particle is within a certain volume. If yes, the resulting wavefunction would be a projection of your wavefunction within this volume. Likewise, for a discrete operator, the projection occurs to a single eigenfunction but for a continuous operator, the projection applies to the continuum of basis function.

Comment: Thank you, greatly clarified!